# Dax calculated column, vlookup max value

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

The goal is for the power pivot table to only show pricing information that corresponds with the last time stamp, all necessary data is in one table.

In normal excel, I would try to solve the problem with a vlookup.

I have tried the below calculated column (along with others) which did not work.  The results is that it reflects the time stamp for that row, not the max time of that day, which then does not provide the desired results on the power pivot.

```
column =
CALCULATE ( MAX ( TabName[Effective Time] ), ALL ( TabName ), TabName[Result] )
    = MAXX (
        FILTER (
            TabName,
            EARLIER ( TabName[Effective Time] ) = TabName[Effective Time]
        ),
        TabName[Result]
    )
```

Here is a example of the output I'm looking for.

For the blue paint product there are two times, 5:00 and 17:00.

It finds the latest time (17:00) and outputs it in the calculated column.

Then repeats grabbing the latest price for each individual product.

| Date | Effective Time | Product | Price | Desired Calculated Column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/13/2021 | 5:00 | Blue Paint | 2.00 | 17:00 |
| 7/13/2021 | 12:00 | Green Paint | 3.00 | 16:00 |
| 7/13/2021 | 17:00 | Blue Paint | 3.00 | 17:00 |
| 7/13/2021 | 16:00 | Green Paint | 2.00 | 16:00 |
| 7/13/2021 | 5:00 | Red Paint | 4.00 | 11:00 |
| 7/13/2021 | 11:00 | Red Paint | 4.00 | 11:00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Column = CALCULATE(MAXX('fact','fact'[Effective Time]),ALLEXCEPT('fact','fact'[Product]))
```

[image: Solution]

If you need to the max of Effective Time by Date-Product grouping use the following

```
Column = CALCULATE(MAXX('fact','fact'[Effective Time]),ALLEXCEPT('fact','fact'[Product],'fact'[Date]))
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using MAXX iterators here?

Comment: Yes in this particular situation the solution can be reached without using MAXX. But my  preference for MAXX is due to the fact that if you are writing a DAX query and need to create a calculated column in one of the derived tables, MAX does not work as it only works on physical tables. The way  I see it, `MAXX` is an all-weather solution.

Comment: It is almost always faster and less memory-intensive to use aggregate functions instead of iterator functions whenever feasible since an iterator has to materialize a table in memory and step through each row of it. For simple computations and small models, there won't often be a significant difference in performance, but as complexity and data size increases, only using iterators when necessary can make a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

The [ALLEXCEPT](https://dax.guide/allexcept/) function is handy for these kinds of situations:

```
Desired Calculated Column =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( TabName[Effective Time] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( TabName, TabName[Product], TabName[Date] )
)
```

This removes all filter context except for the columns specified.